# Best practice way to deal with SIM cards and APNs

Tags: gsm, mobile-data

In my application there is a 2g/4g modem that I control via AT commands.

In general, what is the approach to knowing what APN to specify when setting up a context? I'm trying to avoid hardcoding (or setting via config) this, and want to essentially get the network to tell me.

My understanding (perhaps wrong) is that there's a way to provoke the network to send this info, but I don't know how, or through what medium it's sent. I assume phones do this and then store it.

My application has to be able to deal with a SIM card from any provider being inserted.

Really looking for high level, general guidance on this, or specific AT commands it they are generic.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any feature in the network to get the APN. Gnome use and provide [mobile-broadband-provider-info](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mobile-broadband-provider-info) to choose "default" APN according number of network parameters (mcc/mnc).

More info on documentation : https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/MobileBroadband/ServiceProviders